# Production Mapping "Load Data" Tool having issues with SDE

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, esri-production-mapping

I am attempting to use the Production Mapping tool "Load Data" to import data from many personal databases into a new SDE database (SQL server RDBMS). The schema between the PGDB's and SDE is the exact same.

For some reason, I receive the error

> Target dataset [dataset name] not found or is inaccessible

although I am a dbo and can use the Data Loader or Append tool just fine to accomplish the same task (the Production Mapping tool allows multiple databases to be input at once, which is why I would love to get it working).

I correctly set up a cross-reference database between the databases and validated it, but still no luck.

Might this be a permissions issue? I am looking for a way to avoid tediously appending each dataset to the new SDE.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by editing the cross reference database table "SDEOwner" in MS Access.  The fields were blank for some reason so I input the "SDETargetOwner" as the current data owner, which was "dbo". Not sure why the ArcMap tool doesnt give you the option to enter this when running the tool.